# Image Processing : ImageFilter : can we set the value to Image FIlter

Tags: python

I am building some sample Image editor in Python. I want to set the ImageFilter values on scale change like Blur:

```
filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(float(val)))
```

In blur effect can Change the value on change of scale the..
Same as I have to set the value on scale to other filter effect & according to that the image changes are happen :

```
• ImageFilter.CONTOUR
• ImageFilter.DETAIL
• ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE
• ImageFilter.EDGE_ENHANCE_MORE
• ImageFilter.EMBOSS
• ImageFilter.FIND_EDGES
• ImageFilter.SMOOTH
• ImageFilter.SMOOTH_MORE
• ImageFilter.SHARPEN
```

is there any way to set the imageFilter effect percent/value?
please help...

Answer (score 0):

Visit this site it is might be helpful for your task.
https://www.codementor.io/isaib.cicourel/image-manipulation-in-python-du1089j1u

Comment: I use PIL library